# how to show android wifi setting when wifi is off in unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-wifi

I have a online android game , I want my game check WIFI and if WIFI is off automatic open android WIFI settings . How can send parameter to Android core till show WIFI setting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make Unity-Android plugin.
then you can check WIFI and if WIFI is off automatic open android WIFI settings

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS, 0);
```

Comment: The question here was how to open settings from Unity, not the Android SDK.